# Adding the if condition quits the android app in telephony manager

Tags: java, android, if-statement, telephonymanager

I am trying to make a simple android app in which there is a toast message containing the number of the incoming call. I have stored the number in a string variable. When I display just the toast, it works fine but before the toast, if I add a simple if condition comparing the number to another string, the app quits. The required permissions are given. Can someone help me?

This Works:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String incomingNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This Does not Work (App quits)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String incomingNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
          if(incomingNumber.equals("+919999999999"))
           {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Call from Mom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           else
           {
              Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

    }
```

Comment: "the app quits". Do you get an error? have you debugged your code? what is that value, a default? I don't see anything in that condition or that code that would just "quit"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Maybe if you change .equals() to == it will work

Comment: @Lenin not if it's java code. for javascript, that would be fine, but it isn't javascript

Comment: it won't @Lenin that's just going to cause more bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds a little silly but I just wrapped my "if" condition in a try-catch block and it solved the problem. I am not used to programming in JAVA so it took me a lot to figure out this simple thing. Thank You All for providing me with suggestions :)